# Flutter: ReorderableListView within CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have this design:

[image]

```
CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            const SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Demo'),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Text("sds"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                childAspectRatio: 4.0,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                    child: Text('Grid Item $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: ReorderableListView(
                scrollController: _scrollController,
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (final items in item)
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      key: ValueKey(items),
                      elevation: 2,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(items),
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.work,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
                onReorder: reorderData,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Everything between the `SliverAppBar` and the `ReorderableListView` is just an example of how it should work.

I need to order some elements so for that I use a `ReorderableListView` but this needs to be inside a `CustomScrollView` and using its scroll. Right now everything works except for the scroll. The `SliverAppBar` minimises when scrolling over the grid, but the `ReorderableListView` has it owns scroll.

Is there any way to cancel the second scroll and having these 2 elements working together?

I also uses this library https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables but if you have a look to the repo it seems abandoned (and I faced different issues)

Comment: original error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25789

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: TBH I don't remember